# remove rows from a dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to remove rows from one data frame based on values in another data frame. The following code works for some data frames but not others.

```
df_filter_apply: dataframe from which rows have to be removed
df_filter_input: dataframe that contains input for the filter operation
```

if df_filter_input has a row with
    col1=1,col2=2,col3=1, the remove this row from df_applyfilter data frame.

```
filtered_df=pd.merge(df_filter_apply,df_filter_input, how='outer', indicator=True,on=[col1","col2","col3"])
        rows_in_df1_not_in_df2 = filtered_df[filtered_df['_merge']=='left_only'][df_filter_apply.columns]
        return rows_in_df1_not_in_df2
```

The above code works for some dataframes but for others it gives

```
KeyError: "Index(['index', 'Unnamed: 0'], dtype='object') not in index"
```

The head of the two data frames

```
df_filter_apply  
Unnamed: 0  col1  col2  col3  end sentence  sentence_Id  start text_id  Y_predicted  modified_prediction
 df_filter_input
Unnamed: 0   ItemId  FullSliderMean  FullSliderDev  FullSliderN  GoodSliderMean  GoodSliderDev  GoodSliderN Col1 col2 col3
```

I am attaching an image of first 5 rows with the column values I am trying to filter on.Since it has a lot of columns, I am attaching only a few column values.[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you provide both the dfs.head()

Comment: I added the information

Comment: Shouldn't df.head() return the first 5 lines of your dataframe? I agree that this would be helpful.